# dose JuMP.setRHS apply for non-linear modles in julia?

Tags: julia, julia-jump

In the following code, RHS of NL-constraints should change. but the error happens.
ERROR: UndefVarError: setRHS not defined. could you please learn me why this error happens?. thanks for your helps

```
using JuMP,CPLEX, Ipopt
#parameters--------------------------------------------------------
sig=0.86;
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALT= Model(optimizer_with_attributes(Juniper.Optimizer, "nl_solver"=>optimizer_with_attributes(Ipopt.Optimizer, "print_level" => 0),

       "mip_solver"=>optimizer_with_attributes(CPLEx.Optimizer, "logLevel" => 0),"registered_functions" =>[Juniper.register( :f, 1, f; autodiff = true)])

       )

# variables-----------------------------------------------------------------
f(x) = cdf(Normal(0, 1), x);
JuMP.register(ALT, :f, 1, f; autodiff = true);
@variable(ALT, h >= 0.1);
@variable(ALT, L >= 0.0001);
@variable(ALT, n>=2, Int);
#-------------------------------------------------------------------
@NLexpression(ALT,k7,1-f(L-sig*sqrt(n))+f(-L-sig*sqrt(n)));

@NLexpression(ALT,f2,1/k7)
#constraints--------------------------------------------------------
@NLconstraint(ALT, f(-L) <= 1/400);

@NLconstraint(ALT,rf2,f2<=10000);

#-------------------------------------------------------------------
@NLobjective(ALT, Min, f2)

optimize!(ALT)
JuMP.setRHS(rf2,getvalueNLobjective(1/k7))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using outdated JuMP version examples. As of today  you should use `set_normalized_rhs`:

```
set_normalized_rhs(con_ref, some_rhs_value)
```

Note that this sets the *normalized* RHS that is after it has been pre-computed by JuMP. For example for `@constraint(model, 2x - 5 <= 2)` the normalized value is `7`.

See also https://jump.dev/JuMP.jl/v0.21/constraints/#Constraint-modifications-1 for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kindly help. I use that but it doesn't apply for non-linear constraint.